# Methods/sensors for making a "smart floor" to detect human presence via floor?

Tags: sensor, sensing, pressure

I am looking into making a "smart floor" that can detect when someone steps down onto it. I have done some research and found that the most commonly used sensors are 1) Pressure sensitive floor tiles 2) Electric Field sensors and 3) Vibration sensors.

The pressure sensitive tiles are pretty obvious but i'm not sure what sensors they are using. do they mean piezoelectric floor tiles? I haven't really been able to find help on how i would build one or if there are any commercially available to purchase where i can go to buy them

The Electric field sensors work by measuring changes in electric field when someone is present in the room. I am not sure exactly how but from what i read it seems like you are just stepping on a parallel plate capacitor and measuring the change in the capacitance to determine the amount of pressure.

Vibration sensors came up in my research and i assume they used microphones to detect the peoples steps.

The application:
It will need to detect the presence of a person (and preferably location in the room, but not strictly necessary). It can (hopefully) detect more than one person and estimate how many people are in the room. It's main purpose will be at night where there will be less people walking through the room and people walking less frequently. The room is not huge but not tiny either, probably the size of a typical bedroom. The floor is hard, like marble.

I don't have a set budget but i do want to keep it somewhat reasonable, obviously.

Comment: So, an [occupancy sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupancy_sensor) doesn't work for some reason?

Comment: What are you primarily trying to establish with your project?

Comment: @Samuel, no an occupancy sensor wont work

Comment: @Andyaka, it's for home automation purposes, but i want it done through the floor because i can't mount things on walls.

Comment: You haven't answered my question. What specifically are you trying to record, measure or log with sensors.

Comment: @Andyaka, sorry, i want to measure if a human is present atop the floor. Secondarily, I would like to know how many and where they are in the room.

Comment: A CO2 sensor is surprisingly accurate way to determine if someone is in a room and even how many people are in a room. Its also much simpler to integrate than a strain gauge under an entire floor. The only downside is that you won't have spacial location (room only) and certain applicances will flood the house with CO2 and skew readings (gas stoves and heaters particularly)

Comment: @crasic, i cannot use a C02 censor as the room is exposed to the outside via windows that are always open.

Comment: Unless there is constant wind, diffusion out the window will be at a steady rate, if a person is in the room it will elevate CO2 readings regardless, just less than a closed room. I would spend some quality time testing to see, it may even improve your sensitivity (quick response if someone leaves).

Comment: How many and where they are - and what do you do in response to that information should it be available by some form of measurement i.e. what is your end-game given this data?

Comment: @Andyaka, the end game is literally to say "there is a person in the room", being able to say exactly where and how many of them is a bonus, but i already described my endgame. Just imagine a computer system monitoring the sensor, i want to send the computer TRUE if there is someone and FALSE otherwise. Additional information is just extra details, it would be nice but not necessary. But it NEEDS to be in the floor the way the room is designed.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have three answers to your title question in the first paragraph of your question. To answer the only remaining question, "do they mean piezoelectric floor tiles?", maybe. [This project](http://sean.voisen.org/blog/2013/08/designing-pressure-sensitive-floor/) used [force sensitive resistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-sensing_resistor).

A much cheaper solution to your highly restrictive situation is to use an accelerometer embedded in the floor. You'll have to test it on site to determine the threshold of acceleration (floor vibrations) that will count as a person in the room. It's slightly more socially acceptable than placing a microphone in the room and then telling people "*don't worry, it's not recording your conversations.*"

Answer (score 0):

Pressure-sensing floors usually use piezoelectric sensors.
Most often they are designed as a floating floor with square tiles on top, where each tile is supported by pressure sensors (e.g. load cells) located in the corners of the tile.
Another widespread design is using carpets with embedded piezoelectric sensors.

Localisation of people on this type of floors is possible, with a precision proportional to the number of sensors per area unit.
Some commercial products include floors by [Tarkett](http://www.floorinmotion.com/en/why-floor-in-motion) and [SensFloor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3vikqM1nzc).

You can find more information about sensing floors on Wikipedia.